# como recibo datos con ajax en php pasando con FormData?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy creando un proyecto en el cual tengo un formulario con varios campos de texto y campos de tipo archivo, los cuales estoy tratando de mandar por ajax, la cuestion es la siguiente: 
antes estaba enviando la informacion de la siguiente forma:

```js
function llamado_registro_ajax(){

  var nom_producto = document.formProducto.newProducto.value;
  var precio = document.formProducto.newPrecio.value;
  var id_categoria = document.formProducto.newCategoria.value;
  var descripcion = document.formProducto.newDesc.value;

  $.ajax({

      type:"POST",
      url:"crear_producto.php",
      data:{nom_producto:nom_producto,precio:precio,id_categoria:id_categoria,descripcion:descripcion},

      beforeSend:function(){
          $("#ajaxRepetido").hide("fast");
          $("#ajaxCorrecto").hide("fast");
      },

      success:function(resp){
          $("#ajaxRepetido").hide("fast");
          $("#ajaxCorrecto").hide("fast");
          $("#ajaxCorrecto").hide("fast");

          if(resp==1){
              $("#carga_ajax").hide("fast");
              $("#ajaxRepetido").hide("fast");
              $("#ajaxCorrecto").show("fast");
          }else if(resp==2){
              $("#carga_ajax").hide("fast");
              $("#ajaxRepetido").show("fast");
              $("#ajaxCorrecto").hide("fast");
              document.formProducto.newProducto.style.border = '2px solid red';
          }

      }
  });
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="formProducto" id="formProducto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label for="newProducto">Nuevo producto</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newProducto" name="newProducto" placeholder="Ingrese nuevo producto" onkeyup="val_input(1)">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="newPrecio">Precio</label>
                                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newPrecio" name="newPrecio" placeholder="Precio" onkeyup="val_input(2); formato_miles(this);">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputState">Categoria</label>
                                <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="newCategoria" id="newCategoria" onchange="val_input(3)">
                                    <option selected disabled="" value="0">Seleccione Categoria</option>
                                    <?php
                                    $conector_bd = new DB();
                                    $query_consulta_cat = 'SELECT CA.id_categoria, CA.nom_categoria FROM tb_categoria CA
                                                            WHERE CA.id_est_registro = 1
                                                            ORDER BY CA.id_categoria DESC';
                                    $con_categorias = mysqli_query($conector_bd->connectBD(), $query_consulta_cat);
                                    while ($fila_datos_categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($con_categorias)) {
                                        echo "<option value='" . $fila_datos_categoria['id_categoria'] . "'>" . utf8_encode($fila_datos_categoria['nom_categoria']) . "</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="newDesc">Descripción</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="newDesc" name="newDesc" placeholder="Descripcion del producto" rows="3" onkeyup="val_input(4)"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Subida de imagenes -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="imgProducto">Imagenes para el producto</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group image-upload" style="text-align: center;">
                            <?php
                                for ($c = 1; $c <= 6; $c++) {
                                    echo " 
                                        <label for='imgProducto$c'><img src='../../img/manager/productos/add_img.png' alt='' class='mr-2' title='imagen $c para el producto'></label>
                                        <input type='file' id='imgProducto$c' name='imgProducto$c'>
                                    ";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" onclick="val_formulario()"  style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-dark mb-3">Crear</button>
                        <!-- GIF carga ajax -->
                        <div style="text-align: center" class="ordenAjax" id="carga_ajax">
                            <img src="../../img/loading2.gif" style="width: 50px;">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Alertas controladas por ajax -->
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show ordenAjax" role="alert" id="alertNullFormName">
                            <strong>Ingrese el nombre del nuevo producto.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show ordenAjax" role="alert" id="alertNullFormPrice">
                            <strong>Ingrese el precio del nuevo producto.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show ordenAjax" role="alert" id="alertNullFormCategoria">
                            <strong>Seleccione una categoria.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show ordenAjax" role="alert" id="alertNullFormDesc">
                            <strong>Ingrese una descripcion relacionada al producto.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger animated shake ordenAjax" role="alert" id="ajaxRepetido">
                            <strong>El producto ingresado ya existe en la base de datos.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-success animated fadeInLeft ordenAjax" role="alert" id="ajaxCorrecto">
                            <strong>Producto registrado correctamente.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div id="ajax_respuesta">
                            <!-- respuesta ajax... -->
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

donde le decia el nombre de la variable y se la asiganaba segun correspondia, pero ahora que estoy tratando de adjuntar archivos veo que toca trabajar con algo llamado formdata, {var formData = new FormData($("#formProducto")[0]);} donde le envio los datos del formulario pero lo que no logro entender es como logro recibir esos datos en php para trabajarlos ya que antes solo los recibia por $_POST y ahora solo envio la variable formData en el ajax

```js
function llamado_registro_ajax(){
                                    
    var formData = new FormData($("#formProducto")[0]);
    console.log(formData);return;

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"crear_producto.php",
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,

        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#ajaxRepetido").hide("fast");
            $("#ajaxCorrecto").hide("fast");
        }, 
        /*lo que falta del codigo*/
```

no se si logro hacerme entender, agradeceria una ayuda! :D

Comment: En `crear_producto.php` recibes los valores de tus `input's`, `select's`, etc., con el atributo `name`, por ejemplo `<select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="newCategoria" id="newCategoria" onchange="val_input(3)">` -> el valor de esta etiqueta la recibes en el `php` como `$_POST['newCategoria']`

Comment: oh, vale, muchas gracias!